# Ionic build error: Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory()

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

```
> cordova requirements android

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-28,android-27
Gradle: installed /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/5.4.1/bin/gradle

> cordova build android

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/juliano/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 2s
/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/5.4.1/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 1
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
        
        cordova build android exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: Any Solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems windows defence for controlled folder access was causing the issues. once I turned it off I was able to build for android as usual.